# show highcharts node text from beginning if the text is to long

Tags: highcharts

If the text in the highchart node is longer than the node only a part of the text is displayed. This is okay. But how can I show allways the beginning of the text?

I tried to set verticalAlign to top but this pushes only the displayed text to the top of the node and don't show a other part of the text.

It is the node with

title: Merkmale | Makro zur Prüfung
description: [MORE.OAI] Office AddIn
(370/454,6)
CR: OfficeAddin/DMS-AddIn für MS-Outlook, MS-Excel und MS-Word [OAI]
(/449,1)

It shows

(370/454,6)
CR: OfficeAddin/DMS-AddIn für MS-Outlook,

but it should show

Merkmale | Makro zur Prüfung
[MORE.OAI] Office AddIn

Example `Code https://jsfiddle.net/omurx8Lk/4/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dataLabels.nodeFormat` to control what data label should display. By default dataLabel displayed the description (has higher priority than name) or name.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r5hq2uds/

```
  {
    "id": "17698",
    "name": "Merkmale | Makro zur Prüfung",
    "color": "#AAAAAA",
    "description": "[MORE.OAI] Office AddIn<br/>(370/454,6)<br/>CR: OfficeAddin/DMS-AddIn für MS-Outlook, MS-Excel und MS-Word [OAI]<br/>(/449,1)",
    dataLabels: {
      nodeFormat: '{point.name}'
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.organization.dataLabels.nodeFormat