# show highcharts node text on top if the text is to long

Tags: highcharts

According to this question

[show highcharts node text from beginning if the text is to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61792180/show-highcharts-node-text-from-beginning-if-the-text-is-to-long)

it is possible to use dataLabels.nodeFormat to display only the name which is correct. But the text stands all in one line, and you cant read the whole text "Merkmale | Makro zur Prüfung" because it gets cut off in the end. If you don't use datalabels.nodeFormat the text will be wrapped inside the label automatically. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that using this CSS config is a solution to your issue:

```
.highcharts-data-labels span {
  word-break: break-word !important;
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/36y52qcf/